# MS Dynamics CRM. Custom entity icons

Tags: icons, entity, dynamics-crm, crm

[image]I've set to my custom entity icons by "Update Icons" dialog. There are two sections: "Icon in Web application" and "Icon for Entity forms". Almost everything is OK. But when I create new entity items and view list of these items in Outlook client, I see default icons near each item in the list. How to show my custom icon in the list of entity items in Outlook client? Look at picture.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this issue. Just clean cache 
c:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSCRM\Client\IconCache\
and reopen Outlook